# Alias for instance variables?

Tags: ruby, variables, instance, alias

Is there a way to create aliases for instance variables (not talking about db alias attributes) other than assigning it to another instance var?

For ex:

```
@imavar

alias_attribute(@hesavar, @imavar)
```

Comment: If you rely on ivar names as internal API, I would consider that a code smell.

Comment: Sounds like a code smell - unless it's a temporary measure. Any reason why you want to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can alias getter methods instead.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby doesn't really have attributes.  When you use `attr_reader :imavar` you are creating a method for retrieving the value:

```
def imavar
  @imavar
end
```

So to create an alias for the variable you could create an alias for the method:

```
alias_method :hesavar, :imavar
```

The complete example would be:

```
class DataHolder
  attr_reader :imavar
  alias_method :hesavar, :imavar

  def initialize(value)
    @imavar = value
  end
end

d = DataHolder.new(42)
d.imavar
 => 42
d.hesavar
 => 42
```

Comment: This will make `imavar` public, which imho defeats much of the purpose of aliasing in the first place.